# How to print Palindrome words using Set

Tags: java

I am trying to store & print the number of palindrom words in a string using Set. Please help me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PalindromeCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        String words[] = str.replaceAll("," , " ").split("");


        Set set = new HashSet();
        for(String wordL : words)
        {
         // I am retrieving each word in String and sending it to the sb
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(wordL);
            if(sb.reverse().equals(wordL))// here I am checking whether it is palindrome or not if it is palindrome I am adding to set
            {
                set.add(wordL); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: What problem you are facing? What makes you think that this code [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: `sb.reverse().equals(wordL)` is comparing a `StringBuilder` to a `String`, and will always be false. You probably mean `sb.reverse().toString().equals(wordL)`

Comment: You mean like `set.size()`? Not sure I understand the question..

Comment: Not set.size(), I want to print all the palindrome words in a string which are stored in set

Comment: What Andy said, and you are splitting by empty String, not by space.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify problem you are facing. If you got compilation error add its message, if it is exception add its stacktrace, if you got incorrect result post actual result vs expected result.

Comment: I tried that, But it is not printing the palindrome words

Comment: Andy Turner, Thanks alot, I got the o/p. But one doubt here.
If I give input as "This madam, teaches us about radar"
the o/p I am getting is
[, madam, radar] how to eliminate all punctuation's in string

Comment: You are not getting the punctuation. Since you are removing commas with spaces `" "`, you get space as a single character palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changed snippet of code fixes some of the mistakes you are making.
`split(" ")` splits on the spaces instead of each character for an empty string.
`sb.reverse().toString()` is needed because `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` are not strings.

```
String words[] = str.replaceAll("," , "").split(" ");

Set set = new HashSet();
for(String wordL : words){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordL);
    if(sb.reverse().toString().equals(wordL)){
        set.add(wordL); 
    }
```

You could also use regular-expression to get rid of punctuations and extra spaces.

```
//remove everything not in the alphabet
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]" , " ");
//remove all multiple spaces and replace with a single space
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();

String words[] = str.split(" ");
```

Comment: If I give input as
This madam, teaches us about radar
I am getting the Output as
[, madam, radar]
how to eliminate or remove all special characters

Comment: That is because of trailing spaces. You could use regex to remove both punctuations and multiple spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Use This Code For Your Problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    int st = sc.nextInt();

    Set set = new HashSet();
    int palindrome = st; // copied number into variable
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome != 0)
    {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }
    if (st == reverse)
    {
        set.add(reverse);
    }

    System.out.println(set);
}
```